# EXM Export Sent message recipients

Tags: experience-analytics, exm

There was a button in EXM to export sent message recipients to Excel from the 'Sent email campaigns' page, but the button is missing in EXM 3.3. Is there a way to run such export from the SentMessages page?

[image: export button in EXM3.1]

(it is possible to run the export from the engagement plan supervisor but it requires a lot of clicking + Silverlight)

Comment: if question takes too long. short answer: you can decompile the old version, find the method and look for usings in the newer version

Comment: In new version there are 'pipeline' renderings assigned on this page with 'export to csv' pipeline. But I have no idea what to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible in EXM 3.3+. In EXM 3.4 you're able to see a list of all recipients the message was sent to though, but in EXM 3.3 this report is not available unfortunately.

You can however extract the information either using the API, or directly from MongoDB using a query similar to this:

```
db.Interactions.find( { "Pages.PageEvents": { $all: [ { "$elemMatch" : { ItemId: NUUID("4e0feb94-d408-4208-90da-9e3876181514"), Name: "Email Sent" } }] } })
```

EXM 3.3+ adds an interaction with the "Email Sent" page event for every recipient of the email. ItemId is the item id of the message.